# How to stop a Vim search which is taking too long?

Tags: vim

I am searching for a pattern in a file containing hundreds of millions of lines. Sometimes when I mistakenly enter incorrect search pattern, I am not able to stop that search. I need to wait till it finishes checking the whole file (or if it finds a match) and only then I am able to search for a different pattern. I tried Ctrl+C, but it didn't work.

Killing Vim and reopening is not a good option for me as reopening itself will take longer time.

I'm using OpenSUSE Linux.

`vim --version` output is as shown below.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jun 24 2020 04:02:28)
Included patches: 1-1001
Compiled by zhengchy@plxv1409
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       +tcl
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              +perl              +title
+clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           +python/dyn        +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       -lua               +ruby              +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +X11
+dnd               +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       +xpm
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
```

Comment: Do you mean that you use the `/` command, or how do you search?

Comment: Have you tried pressing Esc?

Comment: @mkrieger1, Yes, I use `/` command to search. Esc doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Two things: the full output of `$ vim --version` is missing from your questions and you should try disabling `:help 'incsearch'` if it is enabled.

Comment: @romainl, I have not enabled 'incsearch'. I have edited the question to include `vim --version` output.

Answer (score -1):

You mean you set the searching path, and your codebase is too large, and when you searching a pattern, this may takes a lot of time.

There are several way to solve this problem:

1. Remove searching path `set path=XXX` in your .vimrc.
2. Change auto-completion plugins. You can use `YouCompleteMe`.
3. Use [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) for regrex searching in your vim.

Hope these advices would help you.

Comment: I am searching within a file and not among many files in a path.